# Foreign keys with mySQL

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, alter-table

I have a table that references a reservation and a product, but I can't add any foreign key.

Here is the table :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `resa_product` (
  `id_reservation` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `id_business` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `id_category` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `id_product` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_reservation`,`id_business`,`id_category`,`id_product`),
  KEY `resa_prod_index` (`id_business`,`id_category`,`id_product`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

The product table :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product` (
  `id_business` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `id_product` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_category` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `nom` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 ...
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_product`,`id_category`,`id_business`),
  KEY `id_category` (`id_category`),
  KEY `id_business` (`id_business`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

but when I try this, I get the errno 150 from mySQL :

```
ALTER TABLE `resa_product`
ADD FOREIGN KEY (`id_business`, `id_category`, `id_product`)
REFERENCES `product`(`id_business, `id_category`, `id_product`)
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE RESTRICT;
```

I don't understand why I can't insert this composed key, although I added an index. Do someone has an idea ?

thanks for your help

Comment: What does the product table look like please?

Comment: What does you `product` table look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the product table

- data type and collation of the 3 columns must match
- there must be a unique constraint or index on the 3 columns in the same order as the FK

Edit: after question update.

Change the foreign key to this to align column order to the PK of product

```
ALTER TABLE `resa_product`
ADD FOREIGN KEY (`id_product`, `id_category`, `id_business`)
REFERENCES `product`(`id_product, `id_category`, `id_business`)
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE RESTRICT;
```

However, the 3 columns appear in different orders all over the show. I'd fix this to be consistent personally...

Comment: Thank you vey much, I didn't understand that index were concatenation of it's differents column, so I didn't think the cols order was important.

Answer (score 1):

Most common reason for this problem is a slight difference between the columns in `products` and `resa_product`. The field types need to be exactly the same, so the size/precision and the sign (unsigned or not) all need to match.